# How is it that we can send signals faster than the speed of light?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

I came across this while reading The Feynmann Lectures on Physics (Vol.1,Ch.7)-

> According to Newton, the gravitational effect is instantaneous, that is, if we were to move a mass, we would at once feel a new force because of the new position of that mass; by such means we could send signals at infinite speed.

Why is it said that *by such means we could send signals at infinite speed*?

Is there any mathematical way to support this?

Comment: Newton happened to be wrong about that, but he didn't have the equipment to know that he was wrong.

Comment: @garyp What is the meaning of sending signal with infinite speed due to gravity?How is gravity and sending signal at infinite speed related?

Comment: If I move an object on a planet orbiting Alpha Centauri, then I would *instantaneously* be able to detect a force on an object on Earth.  I could send Morse code this way, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in the  understanding of [Newtonian gravity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation)
which implies that gravitational force on one object due to other, acts *instantly* over a distance.

Consider following common example:

In Newtonian mechanics, if Sun suddenly disappeared from its position (don't ask how), then Earth would *instantly* leave its orbit and fly off tangentially. Here, the message: 'Hey Earth, Sun has disappeared and there is nothing for you to revolve around. Fly off', is conveyed *instantly, without any time lag*.

Whereas in GR, as we know, it would take about 8 minutes for Earth to recieve the same message and leave the orbit.

Note that in Newtonian gravity, the distance between Earth and Sun is irrelevent. Earth would still leave the orbit *instantly* had it been in Pluto's orbit or a few lightyears away from the Sun. In a way, this means that the message of Sun's disappearance is transmitted to Earth instantly regardless of the distance between the two i.e., at infinite speed. There is no 'speed limit' (as in Relativity) and hence, signals can be sent at infinite speed.

Comment: At last....I found someone who understood my question!!

Answer (score 5):

I keep telling this to people who keep getting deceived by thinking that physics is a representation of nature. NO! Physics is *modeling* of nature. A model is assessed to be correct (or a better word is "accurate") by testing it in experiments. At the time of Newton, his laws were tested only at very low speeds, and by low I mean everything we macroscopically experience on earth at his times, like moving objects of any sort (not exceeding a few tens of kilometers per hour at best). The tests for that kind of speed, which is much smaller than the speed of light, gave accurate results. This includes no limitation in speed whatsoever.

But then science goes on and keeps testing. Some guy called "Einstein" came up with another model, called Special Relativity. His model says that our universe is limited in the speed objects within it can go. It can never exceed the speed of light. He, however, didn't deny or disprove Newton's laws; he just showed that Newton's laws are accurate at very low speed, but the accuracy gets worse when we get closer to the speed of light. We tested his model, and it works! So Relativity is *more accurate* than Newton's mechanics.

Again: Did Einstein disprove Newtonian mechanics? No! it's just a better model of the universe for different conditions. All car and aerodynamics manufacturing companies still use Newton's laws, because they are *accurate enough* and are much easier to use. But high energy particle physics experiments don't use Newton's mechanics always, because it's not accurate enough.

**So the bottom line:** If Newton's laws say we can send signals with infinite speed, it's only true when we show it's true in experiments. This teaches us a lesson that extrapolating the models we make in physics isn't always the accurate way to learn everything about the universe. We should keep testing our models as much as possible to learn more about them and upgrade them like Relativity upgraded Newton's.

Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: This answer appears to be totally unrelated to the question, which was "taking newton's laws as given, how do I send an instantaneous signal?"

Comment: @WillO Actually the question is not so clear. Look in the comments of the question and you'll see that there are people who got the same interpretation of the question as I did.

Comment: Actually, what I see in the comments is one other person interpreting as you did, and the OP immediately correcting him.  I do think your answer is good and correct and worth saying, but I don't think the OP was confused about the issue you're addressing.

Comment: @WillO When I wrote my answer, the comments weren't there, AFAIR. Anyway, like you said. No harm, no foul.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could, for instance, send signals by waggling massive objects around.  In Newtonian gravity such signals would propagate instantly: since

$$\vec{F} = \frac{G m_1 m_2}{|\vec{r}|^2}\hat{\vec{r}}
$$

then if I change $\vec{r}$, $\vec{F}$ changes.  In principle the objects you wiggle don't need to be big: they just need to have some mass.

Well, obviously, that's bad news if we think special relativity is true: you could use this to send information into your own past.  And indeed it turns out not to be correct, and in general relativity such information does not propagate instantly, but at $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Physics is just an effective theory of the observable universe around us. Both Einstein and Newton made their own models of reality which did fit the observations made at their respective times of life. Newton said that the effect of all the forces is instantaneous and this was indeed true on an observational basis. Einstein said that all the forces act at the speed of light and that no information or matter may travel faster than light and this is also consistent with our observations.

As for the signal being sent faster than light, an observer who detects the signal for the first time would not now how long ago that particular signal was produced and he or she would only think that the signal was instantaneous.